# VSCode apply settings to certain file path patterns

Tags: visual-studio-code

In general I want the `files.trimTrailingWhitespace` setting set to `true`.  However, when using jest, the inline snapshots of multi-line strings sometimes end with trailing whitespace, and saving the file removes these characters, causing the tests to fail.

I can turn the setting off for the project as a whole in the `.code-workspace` file, but that's less than ideal.  I was hoping there was something like:

```json
{
  "[**/__tests__/**]": {
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": false
  }
}
```

but that does not seem to be the case.

The workaround for now can just be putting multiline snapshots in the snapshots file directly, installing the [Jest Snapshot Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tlent.jest-snapshot-language-support) extension, and setting:

```json
{
  "[jest-snapshot]": {
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": false
  }
}
```

but again, still less than ideal.

My guess is this feature simply doesn't exist, but I'd love to be wrong about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a perfect answer, but for my purposes (and I'm guessing for most common editor-related cases) it's a good workaround.  The solution is [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) and the [EditorConfig for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig) extension.

#### settings.json

```json
{
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true
}
```

#### my-workspace.code-workspace

```json
{
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": false
}
```

#### .editorconfig

```ini
root = true

[*]
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[**/__tests__/**]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

Ironically, I discovered this solution when looking at VS Code's own repository in hopes of writing code in order to answer this very question.  ‍♀️